# What is the invalid syntax error in this def?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to use [this Anki add-on](https://gist.github.com/eshapard/960f2508c2096ff663af3b6ebc925f16) written in python.

However, on Anki 2.1 startup, an error is returned.

May anyone have a quick look at the short code in the link and spot the error? Maybe it is incompatible with a recent update of python?

```
# Anki 2.0 addon
# Author EJS 
# https://eshapard.github.io/
#
# Sets the learning steps sequence of each deck options group.
from anki.hooks import addHook
from aqt import mw
#from aqt.utils import showInfo
#import time

ignoreList = ['Default', 'OnHold', 'Parent Category'] #Deck options groups to ignore

# run this on profile load
def updateLearningSteps():
   #find all deck option groups
   dconf = mw.col.decks.dconf
   #cycle through them one by one
   for k in dconf:
       if dconf[k]["name"] not in ignoreList:
           #showInfo(dconf[k]["name"])
           ease = dconf[k]["new"]["initialFactor"]/1000.0
           #create learning steps
           tempList = [15]
           for i in range(10):
               l = int(1440*ease**i)
               if l < 28800:
                   tempList.append(l)
               else:
                   gradInts = [(l/1440),(l/1440)]
                   break
           #showInfo(str(tempList))
           #showInfo(str(gradInts))
           mw.col.decks.dconf[k]["new"]["delays"] = tempList
           mw.col.decks.dconf[k]["new"]["ints"] = gradInts
           mw.col.decks.save(mw.col.decks.dconf[k])
   mw.res
et()

# add hook to 'profileLoaded'
addHook("profileLoaded", updateLearningSteps)
```

This is the error: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52420923/66923073-ba2df980-f017-11e9-8b66-c8799db29850.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't match the error. The error has `def updateLearningSteps()` without a colon at the end of the line. That is indeed a syntax error.

Comment: Wow, indeed. I somehow copied the code incorrectly.